# Highcharter - sankey.series.nodes

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, sankey-diagram, r-highcharter

I have implemented a `Sankey diagram` in `JavaScript` using `Highcharts.js`. I am currently trying to implement the same diagram in `R` using `Highcharter` (a wrapper of `Highcharts` for `R`).

My problem is that I am not able to set `sankey.series.nodes` like I did in `JavaScript`. The code for this in `JS` looks like the following:

```
series: [{
            pointPlacement: 'on',
            keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight', 'trx'],
            data: data.data,
            type: 'sankey',
            name: 'Sankey Series',
            nodes: nodes
        }]
```

where `nodes` is an array of objects with the following format:

```
id: product.id,
name: product.product,
trx: product.trx,
color: nodeColor,
```

However, when I do this in `R` nothing happens ..

```
hc_add_series(pointPlacement = 'on',
                data = productData,
                type = 'sankey',
                nodes = nodes,
                name = 'Sankey Series')
```

I am quite lost at the moment and any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Please, always provide a reproducible example. Sometimes your data can not be in the expected format, etc. And it would be helpful if you show the jsfiddle of the higcharts example. Did you tried these examples https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/blob/master/dev/highcharts-v6.R#L43?

Comment: Yes, I have taken a look at these examples already. My case is quite extensive, can't really show the whole code. But the only thing that I am missing is how to set the `nodes` option in `Highcharter`.

Comment: Actually, this is an example of what I want to achieve but in JS: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/css/sankey/

Comment: You can send explicity as a list: `nodes = list(list(id = "Oli", colorIndex = 0), list(id = "Gas", colorIndex = 2), ...)`. You can set `options(highcharter.debug = TRUE)` before run the chart and then in a browser press `CTRL + U` to see the source code and check if the data you gave is the same format as the example you provide

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing, I am using `print(toJSON(hc$x$hc_opts, pretty = TRUE, auto_unbox = TRUE))` in order to see if the data is in the correct format and everything seems to be fine, the sankey diagram is presented but the nodes are not updated ..

Comment: Ok, can you put a minimal reproducible example so I can test please?